# How do I prevent the current scene from rendering during a scene transition with react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a ListView component on Scene A that initially has nothing in it; it's a list of recent search terms tied to the store.

When the user enters a search term and clicks submit on Scene A, the recent search terms store is updated, then we immediately transition to Scene B. I get the "empty section headers" warning from the ListView that I believe is caused by Scene A starting to render as the scene is transitioning.

I tried **using shouldComponentUpdate()** on the Scene A component, but it doesn't seem to fire?! I was hoping to look at the current location and the new location and if they're different return false to prevent updating/rendering.

Anyone have a suggestion for this?

Setting **enableEmptySections={true}** prevents the warning message about empty section headers, but this seems like bandage rather than a permanent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you passing an empty array into the ListView on the initial render and then an array with data once you have it?

If so, its simply a warning that you are rendering a ListView with empty sections which in this case is probably the only section. You can either pass

```
enableEmptySections={true}
```

Or you can do a simple check to see if there is data for the ListView and if not return null instead. When the data comes through the view will re-render with the ListView

In the render function

```
if (!this.state.myVar) return null

return <MyListView myData={this.state.myVar} />
```